# Form Validation for jquery datepicker radio and select field using jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Currently working on form validation where I need to select the date where I am using Jquery UI date picker and i need to validate the date, radio button and option dropdown using jQuery  with jQuery Validation. Currently some how I tried validate all the text fields. But I am not getting how to validate option dropdown, radio and date. When I tried to validate date picker with the normal validation giving required `txt_dob` as a field name it was working fine but when I select the date from the date picker the CSS was not remove.

Kindly please explain me how to do or please provide some sample

Here is my HTML code

```
<form autocomplete="off" class="basicForm" id="basicForm" method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" class="ipt_Field" id="txt_Fname" name="txt_Fname" placeholder="First Name" /> 
<input type="text" class="ipt_Field" id="txt_Mname" name="txt_Mname" placeholder="Middle Name"/>
<input type="text" class="ipt_Field" id="txt_Gname" name="txt_Gname" placeholder="Grandfather's Name"/>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" id="rad_m" value="male" checked>
<label class="radio-label">Male</label>
<input type="radio" name="sex" id="rad_f" value="female">
<label class="radio-label">Female</label>
<select id="sel_ms" class="slt_Field">
    <option>Please Select</option>
    <option value="D">Divorced</option>
    <option value="M">Married</option>
    <option value="S" selected='selected'>Single</option>
    <option value="U">Unspecified</option>
    <option value="W">Widowed</option>
</select>
<label><span class="text-error-black">*</span>Date of Birth</label>
<br/>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="ipt_Field" id="txt_dob" name="txt_dob" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="ipt_Field" id="txt_iDate" name="txt_dob" />
    <span class="form-control-feedback"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
<button class="btn-next" id="btn-Next" >Next</button>
```

Here is the [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/xgLj3r32/)

Comment: Please edit your OP to include the relevant jQuery code.   When the jsFiddle goes dead, the question is useless to future readers.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not getting how to validate option dropdown, radio and date

1. You have specified no validation rules for your `type="radio"` or `select` elements.  Your `select` needs a `name` attribute if you want to validate it.
2. Even so, you've broken it via the `errorPlacement` option.

   ```
   errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
       var n = element.attr("name");
       if (n == "txt_Fname") element.attr("placeholder", "Please enter first name");
       else if (n == "txt_lname") element.attr("placeholder", "Please enter last name");
       else if (n == "txt_Mfname") element.attr("placeholder", "Please enter Mother's Maiden first name");
       else if (n == "txt_Mlname") element.attr("placeholder", "Please enter Mother's Maiden last name");
       else if (n == "txt_Pptnum") element.attr("placeholder", "Please enter your email address");
       else if (n == "txt_Pi") element.attr("placeholder", "Please enter your Place of Issue");
   },
   ```

   You are using the `placeholder` attribute for the error messages and since there is no `placeholder` attribute for `radio` or `select` elements, no error message can be displayed.

   Also, your entire `errorPlacement` concept is too verbose and all the conditionals can simply be replaced with one line...

   ```
   errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
       element.attr("placeholder", error.text());
   },
   ```

   Then the custom error messages are simply contained in the `messages` option...

   ```
   messages: {
       txt_Fname: "Please enter first name",
       ....
   }
   ```
3. Your form loads with a radio already checked, so any validation rule would be satisfied in advance and there would be nothing for the validation plugin to flag.
4. Your form loads with an `option` already selected, so any validation rule would be satisfied in advance and there would be nothing for the validation plugin to flag.
5. You must have `value=""` on the first `option` element.
6. Both of your date input fields have the same `name`.  You must use a unique `name` on each or the plugin can not tell them apart.
7. You have declared rules on field names that do not exist in your HTML markup, and conversely, you have `input` fields that do not have any rules declared.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/xgLj3r32/1/**

This demo fixes your basic mistakes.  However, if you want to use the `placeholder` attribute for error messages, then you'll need to re-write your `errorPlacement` function to conditionally do something else for radio and `select` elements.

---

> When I tried to validate date picker with the normal validation giving required txt_dob as a field name it was working fine but when I select the date from the date picker the CSS was not remove.

Since the plugin does not capture any event associated with the date picker, you need to write a `change` handler that programtically triggers validation when the value of the text field is changed.

```
$('[name="txt_dob2"]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xgLj3r32/2/